# Objective C (UIPickerView): Do Action Once An Item Was Selected

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

On the app that I am developing I have a list of schedule on a `UIPickerView` and what I want to do is to enable a button once the 6th item on the list was selected.

I have this code but I it's not working

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection
        [trainSchedule setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[schedArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
        if ([schedArray objectAtIndex:[schedArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:6]]]) { sendTrainRequest.enabled = YES; } else { sendTrainRequest.enabled = NO; }     
}
```

I have this warning also...

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int
```

How will a able to do what I want to happen?

Comment: Did you set the picker view's delegate to `self`?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam Yes, I did. I edited my question. I added the warning.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to determine if the delegate method is getting called?

Comment: @Jamie Yes, It's getting called.

Comment: pretty hard to help without seeing what 'trainSchedule' and 'schedArray' values are as you step through them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a `UIPickerViewDelegate` method called `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3adidSelectRow%3ainComponent%3a)

Comment: That's what he's using.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam oops lol missed that. Your comment is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your if statement. If I am parsing what you are trying to say correctly,  you want sendTrainRequest.enabled to be set to YES if the sixth item in the picker is selected. Your if statement now is confusing, and the warning is because you are sending on object to the `objectAtIndex` method of schedArray, when you should be sending an integer. Try this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection
    [trainSchedule setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[schedArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
    if ([pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 5) 
        { sendTrainRequest.enabled = YES; } 
    else 
        { sendTrainRequest.enabled = NO; }     
}
```

Note that the hard-coded 5 in this snippet will evaluate to the sixth item in the picker view, since it is zero-referenced.